# How do I obtain the current url without params in Yii?

Tags: php, url, yii, url-routing

I am using Yii.
if my url is `http://localhost/evengee/event/page/id/2/sfn+master/?tab=3`
My real url (file path) is only `http://localhost/evengee`
How would I obtain, preferably in the view:

1. full url `http://localhost/evengee/event/page/id/2/sfn+master/?tab=3`
2. url without explicit parameters `http://localhost/evengee/event/page/id/2/sfn+master/`

I know I can split/explode str_replace by the ? and use $_SERVER. Would prefer to use
Yii native methods.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For:

- full URL (`http://localhost/even/page/id/2/?t=3`) use
  `Yii::app()->request->getUrl()`,
- URL without parameters (`http://localhost/even/page/id/2/` use 
  `Yii::app()->request->getPathInfo()`.

Second one will give you the URL without schema, server and query string. This seems good enough.

Comment: i try `Yii::app()->request->getUrl()`, but this didn't return domain name.

Comment: Use createAbsoluteUrl if you want the full domain name.  
`$this->createAbsoluteUrl( Yii::app()->request->getUrl() );`  
OR  
`Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl( Yii::app()->request->getUrl() );`

Answer (score 5):

To get the full URL, use the `getRequestUrl()` method of `CHttpRequest`
`Yii::app()->request->getRequestUrl();`

You can get the controller, module and action name of the current page from the CApplication methods
`Yii::app()->getController()->id; //gets you the controller id`

`Yii::app()->getController()->getAction()->id; //gets you the action id`

You can piece together a URL using the baseURL property of CApplication

`Yii::app()->baseURL`

Comment: CHttpRequest and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getRequestUrl".  that should be an 'i' not an 'l'

Comment: It should be Yii::app()->request->getUrl();

Answer (score 1):

The best and shorter way I found is:

`Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl(Yii::app()->request->getPathInfo());`

OR

`$this->createAbsoluteUrl(Yii::app()->request->getPathInfo());`

Answer (score 0):

For Yii2, use `\yii\helpers\Url::canonical()`.

Documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#canonical()-detail

Comment: IS this FW still being developed? Question was from 10 years ago

Comment: Yes it is. Yii2 is the current version. Yii3 is in active development. https://www.yiiframework.com/